# How to use IN as exactly match using SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a system that monitors phones. As we all know, phones can have one sim or two. It's a known fact that there are differents operators. So I want to show a filter with all possibles combinations of phones and operators. Today I have an universe of 10k devices. In the end the system shows devices measurements but user's may filter those statistics by phone's manufacturer (**apple**, **samsung**, **nokia**, etc etc), model and **operators**.

So I have this form that would show all currently combinations using my device universe.

In the end I have the filter like this:

```
<select id="filter" multiple="multiple">
      <optgroup label="Model">
            <option value="1">iPhone</otion>
            <option value="2">Samsung</otion>
            <option value="3">Asus</otion>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="Operator">
            <option value="1">Digicel</otion>
            <option value="2">FLOW</otion>
            <option value="3">Rogers</otion>
            <option value="4">Telus</otion>
            <option value="5">Bell</otion>
            ...
            ...
            <option value="2,3">FLOW,Rogers</otion>
            <option value="2,5">FLOW,Bell</otion>
            <option value="3,1">Rogers,Digicel</otion>
            ...[I don't know all current combinations..this is a dynamic filter]
      </optgroup>
</select>
```

**Database Model**

So I have the main table of devices (I'm going to put only columns that "matters"):

```
devices
------------   
id_device (pk) | id_manufacter (fk) | id_model (fk)
------------   
 1 | 1  | 10
 2 | 1  | 13
 3 | 1  | 14
 4 | 2  | 5
 4 | 2  | 6
 ..........
 99| 60 | 811
 ..........


operators
------------   
id_operator (pk) | operator_name | operator_ip
------------   
 1 | "Digicel"  | 10.192.112.29
 2 | "FLOW"     | 10.192.112.33
 3 | "Rogers"   | 10.192.112.54
 4 | "Telus"    | 10.192.112.111
 5 | "Bell"     | 10.192.112.233
 ..........
 4654 | "Vivo"     | 10.192.112.44
 ..........
```

The IP address I use to do some measurements - it's irrelevant for now - and of course these are fake ips.

And I have this intermediate table:

```
------------   
id_device | id_operator
------------   
 1 | 1
 1 | 2
 2 | 1
 3 | 3
 4 | 2
 4 | 3
 5 | 2
 5 | 5
 6 | 2
 6 | 5
 .........
 129129 | 3
 129129 | 1
```

**What I want:**

A *way* or an *idea* - as you prefer - to filter by "exclusive" options. If I choose option `<option value="2,5">FLOW,Bell</otion>` it will return all devices that has this SIM combination: `2,5`. In this case - with few records - device's id **5**and **6** should be returned.

Users may choose

```
<option value="1">Digicel</otion>
<option value="3">Rogers</otion>
<option value="2,3">FLOW,Rogers</otion>
<option value="2,5">FLOW,Bell</otion>
```

In this case it should return all devices that has only SIM with operator#1 or SIM with operator#3 or SIMs with operator's #2 AND operator's #3 or SIMs with operator's #2 AND operator's #5:

> devices #2,#3,#4,#5,#6.

In the database I created a package with the follow `function`:

```
FUNCTION generalMeasurements (
   models             IN   VARCHAR2,
   manufacturers      IN   VARCHAR2,
   idsoperators       IN   VARCHAR2
)
   RETURN sys_refcursor 

IS

vmanufacturers table_string := str2table(manufacturers);
vidmodels table_string := str2table(models);

cout sys_refcursor;

BEGIN
    open cout for
    select count(*), bla bla bla
      from devices inner join operators_device on id = id_device
        inner join operator on id_operator = operator_id
        WHERE (   (models IS NULL)
                  OR id_model IN (
                                         SELECT COLUMN_VALUE
                                           FROM TABLE
                                                     (vidmodels))
                 )
             AND (   (manufacturers IS NULL)
                  OR id_manufacturer IN (
                                            SELECT COLUMN_VALUE
                                              FROM TABLE
                                                        (vmanufacturers))
                 );

END;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE table_string IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(30);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION str2table (p_str IN VARCHAR2)
   RETURN table_string
IS
   l_str    LONG         DEFAULT p_str || ',';
   l_n      NUMBER;
   l_data   table_string := table_string ();
BEGIN
   LOOP
      l_n := INSTR (l_str, ',');
      EXIT WHEN (NVL (l_n, 0) = 0);
      l_data.EXTEND;
      l_data (l_data.COUNT) := LTRIM (RTRIM (SUBSTR (l_str, 1, l_n - 1)));
      l_str := SUBSTR (l_str, l_n + 1);
   END LOOP;

   return l_data;
END;
```

So... any ideas to do that?

Comment: This makes no sense. Why did you write the first query? Whatever you are trying to do **in the end**, it is a lot easier to do with the original data than to do with the comma-separated strings. And it almost certainly does not require any PL/SQL at all (procedure/function, much less package) - it only requires a plain SQL query. Please explain the original input (you probably already have, it's table1) and the requirement, with no reference to your attempted solution. We can guess some of the requirement, but it must be more precise.

Comment: For example: what if you are searching for option **10, 60** and `id = 9` has `id_name`s 10, 60 and 96? Is that OK? In that case, you just want the rows with 10 and 60 returned? Also, can there be duplicate `id, id_name` (that is, two rows with the same `id` and same `id_name`)? Can any of the columns have `null` in them?

Comment: @mathguy if I search for option 10, 60 and id = 9 has id_names 10, 60 and 96? Id#9 should not appear in result set as i'm searching exactly for ids which `id_name` matches exactly 10 and 60. None of these columns (id, id_name and name) can be null. Also it can have duplicated `id_name` and `name` only.

Comment: OK, and I assume if `id=9` has `id_name` 10, 10, 60 - that is OK? (duplicate) - and you want all the rows returned?

Comment: No... In this case I would have another option to filter: 10, 10, 60. I know it sounds weird... but in this case we'd know also that there is a registration issue. There is no reason for this case to exist...but if he does, it's another option in the filter..

Comment: what did you try? it seem you are asked us to do everything, this is not how it work.

Comment: @Fredou I tried with traditional `IN` but won't do the job since it's a different way... I'm not looking for a solid solution. I'm looking for ideas to accomplish what I want.

Comment: @mathguy we are talking about phones and operators. We can have a phone with a dual chip right? Can we use a dual chip with two lines for the same operator? It's possible...but pointless. So the normal case is to have only one chip and one operator. But I can also have two operators.. or maybe more. you never know :P

Comment: Please elaborate on your efforts and results with `traditional in`.

Comment: How are you passing in the inputs? Such as 10, 60 as opposed to 10, 10, 60?

Comment: @mathguy a single string like "10,60;10,10;60". I can also choose `ids_option` like this: "10" or "20" or "10;20" or "10;20;10,60".

Comment: So you're passing a single string that has multiple sets of values separated by semicolons, and each set is separated by commas? It seems like you're trying to make life hard for yourself. Is it possible to change the input to a collection (or, if really necessary, a collection of collections)? What result do you want with multiple sets of values passed in?

Comment: I'm passing a single string to my procedure. My procedure uses a function to transform string into table (So I can use `IN`). Yes I can change this but is it so bad the way it is?

Comment: @mathguy I've edited the entire question... I think it's easier to understand now. Can you take a look please?

Comment: I have a dual sim phone, with two different numbers but same operator.. ;)

Comment: in your example you have an error.. for options like '1;3;2,3;2,5' the result should be devices #2,#3,#4,#5,#6, isn't it? you missed #4 which match 3rd option '2,3'

Comment: @MtwStark sure! Fixed :)

Comment: glad to know, it means I have well understood the problem. I have written solution syntax for sql-server, I'm trying to translate it to oracle, when I'm ready I will post the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've already added an answer which works correctly, but have since found out that Oracle has an [aggregation function](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques) for constructing comma-delimited lists.

That makes this query quite simple (and as a bonus uses the `IN` keyword!):

```
select  *
from    (
            select  id_device,
                    /* Create comma delimited list of operators for each device */
                    LISTAGG(id_operator, ',') 
                    WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id_operator) AS op_list
            from device_operators
            group by ID_device 
        ) As a
 where  op_list in ('1','2,3','2,5','3')
```

See [this SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/812ea/1) for an equivalent working version in Postgres (Oracle isn't working in SQLfiddle for some reason).

Comment: very smart, just pay attention on how you build options in your html `<option value="2,5">FLOW,Bell</otion>` will work, but `<option value="5,2">Bell,FLOW</otion>` will not. Personally I prefer your 1st answer.

Comment: Thanks!  I reckon my 1st answer is potentially more robust.  I'd be interested to know what how the performance compares.  This way is definitely only usable if you keep tight control over the input selections.

Comment: @MtwStark the html is formed by `op_list` from Alex's. :)

Answer (score 1):

For this answer, I have assumed that you will be able to get the chosen options into a temporary table of some sort - I've named the table `selected` with column name `id_list`.

My approach is to do a broad join on the intermediate table and the temporary table.  This allows us to get the total number of rows with matching records.

Then it's just a matter of counting the number of matching rows and ensuring that it matches:

- The number of items in the chosen option, and
- The number of operators associated with the device

The attached [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/2df315/1) uses sqlite, as the oracle version wasn't working properly.  It should be easily translatable to oracle though - I think the only thing you will need to do is switch the order of the first two parameters in the `replace` function.

```
select  b.id_device,
        num_device_records,
        num_id_records,
        id_list,
        count(*) as num_occurrences
from    ( 
            select  id_list,
                    /* We need the number of ids that appear in each list */
                    length( id_list ) - length( replace( id_list, ',', '' ) ) + 1 
                    as num_id_records
            from    selected
        ) as a

        inner join
        device_operators as b
        /* Join the two tables on records where
           the id_operator can be found in the id_list */
        /* Note that I have added a comma to the 
           beginning and end of each to "anchor" the search */
        on ','|| a.id_list ||',' like  '%,'||b.id_operator||',%'

        left join (
            /* We also need to total number of times each device appears */
            select  id_device,
                    count(*) as num_device_records
            from    device_operators
            group by id_device
        ) as c
        on b.id_device = c.id_device
group by b.id_device,
        num_device_records,
        id_list
/* We only want records where the aggregated number of 
   device records is equal to both the number of ids in 
   the list and the number of occurrences of that device 
   in the device_operators table */
having  num_device_records = num_id_records
        and num_device_records = num_occurrences
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Quite interesting problem..

My approach is

1. test all relations against all requested options
2. identify non matching ones
3. subtract non matching ones from good ones

I assume options passed as a single string in the form:

```
"opt_val_1;opt_val_2;..opt_val_n"
```

where each `opt_val` will be in the form:

```
"operator_1,operator_2..operator_n"
```

I wrote it for sql-server, which is the dbms I best know, then I have translated it to ORACLE, I have tested it on Oracle live SQL, but maybe there is a better syntax..

the query should be:

```
WITH 
-- this is your parameter
OPTIONS AS (
    SELECT '1;3;2,3;2,5' OPT_VAL FROM DUAL
),
-- this is the splitted list of options
opt as (
    select id opt_n, val opt_val 
    from (
        select ROWNUM id, regexp_substr(OPT_VAL,'[^;]+', 1, level) VAL
        from OPTIONS
        connect by regexp_substr(OPT_VAL, '[^;]+', 1, level) is not null
    ) x
),
-- this is the list of devices with relations
dev as (
    select distinct id_device
    from relations
)

-- this is the list of devices exploded by options
select * 
from (
    select o.opt_n opt_n, dr.id_device
    from dev dr
    cross join opt o
) dr

minus 

-- this is the list of invalid devices exploded by options
select * 
from (
    select distinct COALESCE(r.opt_n,o.opt_n) opt_n, COALESCE(o.id_device, r.id_device) id_device
    from (
        select dr.id_device, s1.opt_n opt_n, s1.opt_val, s2.Id dev_n, s2.val id_operator
        from dev dr
        cross join opt s1
        cross apply (
            select *
            from (
                SELECT ROWNUM id, regexp_substr(sx.opt_val,'[^,]+', 1, level) val
                FROM (select s1.opt_val opt_val from dual) sx
                connect by regexp_substr(sx.opt_val, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
            ) x
        ) s2
    ) o
    full join (
        select  ID_DEVICE,  ID_OPERATOR, OPT_N, OPT_VAL
        from relations r
        cross join opt o
    ) r
    on (o.id_device=r.id_device)  and (o.opt_n = r.opt_n)  and (o.id_operator = r.id_operator)
    where o.id_device is null or r.id_device is null
) x
order by 1,2
```

and this is the output:

```
opt_n   id_device
1       2
2       3
3       4
4       5
4       6
```

Let me know if this is what you are looking for

Comment: Hey mate thanks for your time. Your solution works good. But personally I think a bit complicated (or too advanced) to use...That's why I won't accept as answer. But it's a good solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you for your upvote anyway. Don't worry, you have accepted the best answer, or a least the smartest (read my comment on accepted answer).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't read the question before the OP edited it so this is my solution proposal as i understand by now.

First of all, always work with a sorted pair for the operators selected to filter. This way, we always have to compare with two values. When the filter criterion is only composed by one operator, reuse the value selected to compose the tupla. The option value box should appear this way:

```
  <option value="1,1">Digicel</option>
  <option value="2,2">FLOW</option>
  <option value="3,3">Rogers</option>
  <option value="4,4">Telus</option>
  <option value="5,5">Bell</option>
  ...
  ...
  <option value="2,3">FLOW,Rogers</option>
  <option value="2,5">FLOW,Bell</option>
  <option value="1,3">Rogers,Digicel</option>
```

Next, we only have to group and select what we need with the creterion selected by the user.

```
select * 
  from (select intermediateTable.idDevice,
               min(intermediateTable.idOperator) idOperator1,
               max(intermediateTable.idOperator) idOperator2
          from intermediateTable
         -- Consider apply filter clause over idDevice when exists filters specified by the user
       group by intermediateTable.idDevice) 
  where (idOperator1 = firstUserSelectCriterionLowerElement and idOperator2 = firstUserSelectCriterionUpperElement) 
     or (idOperator1 = secondUserSelectCriterionLowerElement and idOperator2 = secondUserSelectCriterionUpperElement)
     or (idOperator1 = thirdUserSelectCriterionLowerElement and idOperator2 = thirdUserSelectCriterionUpperElement)
     .....
     or (idOperator1 = nthUserSelectCriterionLowerElement and idOperator2 = thdUserSelectCriterionUpperElement)
```

Where there is no opertor criterion selected, dont apply the outer query where clauses. Using the example proposed by the OP, where the user choose is:

```
 <option value="1,1">Digicel</otion>
 <option value="3,3">Rogers</otion>
 <option value="2,3">FLOW,Rogers</otion>
 <option value="2,5">FLOW,Bell</otion>
```

the query should be builded as this:

```
select * 
 from (select intermediateTable.idDevice,
           min(intermediateTable.idOperator) idOperator1,
           max(intermediateTable.idOperator) idOperator2
      from intermediateTable
   group by intermediateTable.idDevice) 
where (idOperator1 = 1 and idOperator2 = 1) 
   or (idOperator1 = 3 and idOperator2 = 3)
   or (idOperator1 = 2 and idOperator2 = 3)
   or (idOperator1 = 2 and idOperator2 = 5)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hey mate. Thanks for your time. Unfortunately I can't hardcode my options... Users may choose more than one option.. I got your idea though. But I don't think it fits. I still think I can use operator `IN` to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has a nice IN feature, it can compare lists against list of lists
So at client side convert user input into a table form (or use splitting at server side ).

```
CREATE TABLE device_operators
    (id_device int, id_operator int)
;
INSERT INTO device_operators
    (id_device, id_operator)
VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (1, 2),
    (2, 1),
    (3, 3),
    (4, 2),
    (4, 3),
    (5, 2),
    (5, 5),
    (6, 2),
    (6, 5)
;


CREATE TABLE selected
    (op1 int, 
    op2 int)
;
```

Simulates the user input.

```
INSERT INTO selected
    (op1,op2)
VALUES
    (1, null),
    (3, null),
    (2,3),
    (2,5)
;
```

The query

```
select t.id_device
from (select id_device
       , min(id_operator) op1
       , max(id_operator) op2 
      from device_operators
      group by id_device
      ) t
join selected s
 on (t.op1, t.op2) in ((s.op1, coalesce(s.op2, s.op1)))             
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for this short reply, but this select will do it

```
select i1.id_device from intermediate i1 where i1.id_operator  = 2
and EXISTS 
       ( select * from intermediate i2 where i2.id_operator = 5 and i2.id_device = i1.id_device)
```

You can also use INTERSECT (I cannot try it right now, but will be something like that...

```
select id_device from intermediate where id_operator = 2
INTERSECT
select id_device from intermediate where id_operator = 5
```

Sorry, but I'm in a hurry and can't explain it better right now

EDIT:
I can see you are quite interested in using IN for solving this question, but IN is not exclusive, anyway, using IN, you can do something like...

```
select id_device from intermediate where id_operator in (2, 5) 
group by id_device 
having count(*) = 2
```

Ah, and you have duplicated rows... well, then maybe something like...

```
select id_device from (
        select distinct * from intermediate where id_operator in (2, 5) )
group by id_device
having count(*) = 2
```

Anyway I think is a good idea to get rid of the duplicated entries

Answer (score -1):

If you want to select ids that have exactly a given set, you can do:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having sum(case when id_name in (10, 60) then 1 else 0 end)) = 2 and
       count(*) = 2;
```

If two rows can have exact duplicates, then use:

```
having sum(case when id_name = 10 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when id_name = 60 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       count(distinct id_name) = 2
```

You can get the corresponding rows in several ways.  One way uses `in`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id in (select id
               from t
               group by id
               having sum(case when id_name in (10, 60) then 1 else 0 end)) = 2 and
                      count(*) = 2
              );
```

Comment: hmmm....... thanks for your time mate. I'm going to test this tomorrow and I'll return with a feedback.

Comment: Please see the comments under the original question - the OP stated explicitly that there MAY be duplicates by `id, id_name`. So the count may be 2 if an `id` has the `id_name=10` twice and no `id_name=60`. This is why we ask OP's for complete details of their requirement in the first place.

Comment: Gordon, I've edited the entire question... I think it's easier to understand now. Can you take a look please?